# Как сделать аггрегированную таблицу по значениям списков

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Есть DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'letters': [['a'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c' ,'d']],
                   'values': [1, 10, 100, 1000]})
```

| letters | values |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a, b | 10 |
| a, b, c | 100 |
| a, b, c, d | 1000 |

Нужно посчитать сумму значений для каждой буквы, чтобы на выходе получилась такая таблица:

| letters | sum_values |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1111 |
| b | 1110 |
| c | 1100 |
| d | 1000 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = df.explode("letters").groupby("letters").sum().reset_index()
```

res:

```
  letters  values
0       a    1111
1       b    1110
2       c    1100
3       d    1000
```